# React Native ScrollView will not expand with child size

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building an app which uses the Map method to build several different components. I have a scrollview which contains the whole page. Currently, the scrollView won't expand to contain everything despite trying what is seemingly every bit of advice online.

I have tried having the scrollview be inside another view but that still doesn't work as well as a combination of different flex configurations. Does anyone know why this page in particular isn't working. I have compared it to other pages and there is seemingly no reason as to why the flex does not extend.

Thanks

```
render(){
    return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}} >
      <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
          <View style={styles.photoShowcase }>
                    {
                    this.state.images.map((item, key) => (
                        <Image key = {key} source={{uri: item}} style = {{width: 200, height: 200}} />
                    ))
                    }
            </View>
            <View style = {styles.cameraContainer}>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleChoosePhoto}>
                    <Icon type='font-awesome' name='photo' size={60} />
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <Icon type='font-awesome' name='camera' size={120} />
                <Icon type='font-awesome' name='map-o' size={60} />
            </View>

            <View style= {styles.detailsContainer}>
                <View >
                    <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => {this.setState({title: text})}} style = {styles.title} >New Day Title </TextInput>
                </View>
                <View style = {styles.description}>
                    <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => {this.setState({description: text})}} multiline={true}>Description for the text goes here</TextInput>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style = {styles.friendsContainer}>
                <View>
                    <Text style = {styles.friendsSectionTitle}>I spent today with: </Text>
                </View>
                <ScrollView horizontal= {true}>             
                    <View style={styles.peopleContainer}>
                        {
                            this.state.friends.map((item, key) => (
                                <View key={key} >
                                     <TouchableHighlight >
                                        <PersonEntryBox  name={item.name} backgroundImageToUse={item.image} style = {styles.smallBox} functionToRun = {() => {this.state.selectedFriends.push(item)}} />
                                    </TouchableHighlight>
                                </View>
                                ))
                        }
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>                
             </View>
             <View style={{height: '40%', width: '100%'}}>
                <MapView 
                        style={{...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}}
                        initialRegion={{
                            latitude: 45.5209087,
                            longitude: -122.6705107,
                            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                    }}

                    onPress={this.handlePress}
                >
                    {this.state.markers.map((marker) => {
                        return (
                            <Marker {...marker} >
                                <View style={styles.marker}>
                                    <Text style = {styles.markerText}>{marker.cost}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </Marker>
                        )
                    })}
                </MapView>
             </View>

            <View style = {styles.ratingsButtonContainer}>
                <RateTheDayBox style={styles.badDay} dayRating="Bad" onClick={() => {this.state.rating ="red"; this.storeDay()}}></RateTheDayBox>
                <RateTheDayBox style={styles.okayDay} dayRating="Okay" onClick={() => {this.state.rating = "yellow"; this.storeDay()}}></RateTheDayBox>
                <RateTheDayBox style={styles.greatDay} dayRating="Great" onClick={() => {this.state.rating = "green"; this.storeDay()}}></RateTheDayBox>
            </View>
            </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
}}
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    pageContainer: {
        paddingTop: 50,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 1,
    },
    mapContainer:{
        flex: 1,   
    },
    marker: {
        backgroundColor: "#550bbc",
        padding: 5,
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
    text: {
        color: '#FFF',
        fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    photoShowcase: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        zIndex: 0,
        height: 200
    },
    cameraContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingTop:20,
        paddingLeft: '5%',
        paddingRight: '5%',
        width: '100%',
        height: '25%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
    },
    iconStyles: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        color: 'red',
    },
    detailsContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '35%',
    },
    title: {
        paddingLeft: 10,
        fontSize: 40,
        textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    },
    description: {
        paddingLeft: 11,
        paddingTop: 10,
    },
    friendsContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '20%',
    },
    boxContainers: { 
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    friendsSectionTitle: {
        paddingLeft: 10,
        fontSize: 30,
    },
    ratingsButtonContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '20%',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
    badDay: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
    okayDay: {
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },
    greatDay: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
    },
    peopleContainer: { 
        paddingTop: 10,
        flex: 1, 
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        justifyContent: 'center', 
        alignItems: 'center' ,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
    },
});
```

**EDIT: For anyone suffering from the same issue, REMOVE PERCENTAGES FROM HEIGHTS. This fixed this issue for me.**

Comment: Can you reproduce in snack.expo.io?

Comment: Is there a way to upload the whole folder to snack? I have just tried but my file has so many integrated parts

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I was using percentages to change the height of many of the items. when the page had items added to it the styles were not in the state so they were not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use style instead of contentContainerStyle ? the doc says :

> These styles will be applied to the scroll view content container which wraps all of the child views

So maybe here is your problem, you're not applying the flexGrow to the scrollView but to its wrapper

Comment: That was a very good suggestion that I thought would work, however, It still doesn't work  which is disappointing

Comment: I figured it out, the styles had height in them which included percentages, for some reason that broke the scrollview